# Cursor loader not refreshing cursor

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

Hi i am making a movies app. In `main fragment` i am showing `grid images` and in `detail fragment` i am showing `movie details` and there is a `checkbox` in `detail fragment` through which a user can select a movie as favorite.

Now when user selects a movie as favorite i update the database but when i return to `main fragment` and check for movies whose favorite value is one the data is not updated.

I have set `notification uri` in `content provider` and when i use `restart loader` instead of `init loader` it works but i want it to work with `init loader` as i read somewhere it will be fast and efficient.

MainFragment.java

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment implements MovieTask.OnTaskCompleted,LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>  {
@Bind(R.id.recycler_view)RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
@Bind(R.id.progress_bar)ProgressBar progressBar;
public static String API_KEY;
private CardViewAdapter cursorAdapter;
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
private ArrayList<Movie> mMovieArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public MoviesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(Utility.checkNetwork(getActivity())){
    cursorAdapter = new CardViewAdapter(getActivity(), null, 1);  }
    //Initialising recycler view
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2));
    API_KEY = getString(R.string.API_KEY);
    updateData();
    return rootView;
}

//To check setting value and call AsyncTask to get json data
private void updateData(){
    //checking preference value
    String order = Utility.getPreferenceValue(getActivity());
    if(Utility.checkNetwork(getActivity())){
        if(order.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.pref_fav))){
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
        }else {
            new MovieTask(getActivity(), order, this).execute();
        }
    }else { withoutNet(); }
}

//Tasks to do without internet
private void withoutNet(){
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.network), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.fav_toast), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//Getting data from database
private void getDataFromDb(Cursor cursor) {
    mMovieArrayList.clear();
    mMovieArrayList = Utility.getDataFromCursor(cursor);
    if (mMovieArrayList.size() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.no_selection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    setCursorAdapter(cursor);
}

//Setting adapter to grid view and passing details to detail activity
public void setAdapter(){
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adapter.setList(mMovieArrayList);
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            startActivityFromMain(mMovieArrayList.get(position));
        }
    }));
}

//Setting cursor adapter
public void setCursorAdapter(Cursor cursor){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            startActivityFromMain(mMovieArrayList.get(position));
        }
    }));
}


//To start detail activity
public void startActivityFromMain(Movie movie){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Utility.MOVIE, movie);
    if(Utility.getPreferenceValue(getActivity()).equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.pref_fav))) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, Utility.FAV_CODE);
    }else {
        startActivityForResult(intent, Utility.OTHERS_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==Utility.SETTINGS_CODE||requestCode==Utility.FAV_CODE){
        updateData(); }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Utility.SETTINGS_CODE);
            return true;
    }
    return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//Interface method
@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(ArrayList<Movie> movie) {
    mMovieArrayList = movie;
    setAdapter();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MovieContract.FavoriteMovies.CONTENT_URI, null,
            MovieContract.FavoriteMovies.COLUMN_FAVORITES + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(1)}, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    getDataFromDb(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {}
}
```

Here when `loader` is finished i call `getDataFromDb` method which calls `setCursorAdapter` method which swaps `cursor` for `recycler view`.The problem is when i return back from `detail fragment` loader `onFinished()` method is not called.

ContentProvider:

```
public class MovieProvider extends ContentProvider{
//constants for uri matcher
private static final int TABLE = 1;
private static final int TABLE_ID = 2;
private static final UriMatcher mUriMatcher;
private SQLiteOpenHelper mOpenHelper;

static {
    mUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(MovieContract.AUTHORITY, FavoriteMovies.TABLE_NAME, TABLE );
    mUriMatcher.addURI(MovieContract.AUTHORITY, FavoriteMovies.TABLE_NAME + "/#", TABLE_ID);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mOpenHelper = new MovieDatabase(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    switch (mUriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case TABLE:{
            cursor = db.query(FavoriteMovies.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
            break;
        }
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Uri" + uri);
    }
    if(getContext()!=null)
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return cursor;
}

@Override
public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
    switch (mUriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case TABLE:
            return FavoriteMovies.CONTENT_TYPE;
        case TABLE_ID:
            return FavoriteMovies.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Uri" + uri);
    }
}

@Override
public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Uri uri1=null;
    switch (mUriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case TABLE:{
            long id = db.insert(FavoriteMovies.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            if(id!=-1){
                uri1 = MovieContract.getUriForId(id);
            }
            break;
        }
        default:{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Uri For Insertion " + uri);
        }
    }
    if(getContext()!=null)
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return uri1;
}

@Override
public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int delete;
    switch (mUriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case TABLE_ID:{
            delete = db.delete(FavoriteMovies.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        }
        case TABLE:{
            delete = db.delete(FavoriteMovies.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        }
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Uri For Deletion " + uri);
    }
    if(getContext()!=null&&delete!=0)
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return delete;
}

@Override
public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int update;
    switch (mUriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case TABLE_ID:{
            update = db.update(FavoriteMovies.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        }
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Uri For Updating " + uri);
    }
    if(getContext()!=null)
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return update;
}
}
```

Comment: Do not notify Cursor in query of provider, but register for notification...

Comment: Thanx it solved the issue.